# Find a two-dimensional array to find the sum of multiple elements without loop?

Tags: php, arrays

my array:

```
$data = [
0 => [
    "id" => "23",
    "to_user_id" => "6",
    "from_user_id" => "1",
    "month" => "201810",
    "add_time" => "1540795976",
    "f1" => 10,"f2" => 0,"f3" => 0,"f4" => 0, "f5" => 0,"f6" => 55,"f7" => 0,"f8" => 0,"f9" => 77,"f10" => 0,"f11" => 0,"f12" => 99,"f13" => 77,"f14" => 66,"f15" => 55,
    "score" => 0
],
1 => [
    "id" => "24",
    "to_user_id" => "6",
    "from_user_id" => "1",
    "month" => "201810",
    "add_time" => "1540795976",
    "f1" => 10,"f2" => 0,"f3" => 0,"f4" => 0, "f5" => 0,"f6" => 55,"f7" => 0,"f8" => 0,"f9" => 77,"f10" => 0,"f11" => 0,"f12" => 99,"f13" => 77,"f14" => 66,"f15" => 55,
    "score" => 0
]
];
```

I need to get the sum of f1-f15. here is my code:

```
echo array_sum(array_map(function ($val){
            return $val['f1']+$val['f2']+$val['f3']+$val['f4']+$val['f5']+$val['f6']+$val['f7']+$val['f8']+$val['f9']+$val['f10']+$val['f11']+$val['f12']+$val['f13']+$val['f14']+$val['f15'];
        },$data));
```

It doesn't look too good, is there a better way to implement it? thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array_filter with regex to select only needed keys

```
$res = [];
foreach($data as $item) {
    $res[] = array_sum(array_filter($item, function ($x) { return preg_match('/^f\d+$/', $x); }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY ));
}
print_r($res);
```

[**demo**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9cd80e1c379c668c4decf0f41a6f0f369bc2ad37)

Comment: Nice use of `array_filter`.

Comment: Although not entirely sure about the requirement *without loop*

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on what you are already doing, but changing the way that the items are extracted.  This uses another array of the keys your after and then uses [`array_intersect_key()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-key.php) to filter out all of the other values and then uses `array_sum()` instead of the adding each item together...

```
$extract = ["f1" => 0, "f2" => 0, "f3" => 0, "f4" => 0, "f5" => 0,
    "f6" => 0, "f7" => 0, "f8" => 0, "f9" => 0, "f10" => 0, "f11" => 0,
    "f12" => 0, "f13" => 0, "f14" => 0, "f15" => 0 ];

echo array_sum(array_map(function ($val) use ($extract) {
    return array_sum(array_intersect_key($val, $extract));
}, $data));
```

Comment: `$extract = array_fill_keys(["f1","f2",..], 0);` ?

Comment: @splash58, that would also work, more interested in the main processing though.